# representing matrix by linkedlist

Tags: c++, list, matrix

The problem is:

> An alternative linked representation for sparse matrices uses nodes that have the fields down, right,
>       roe, col, and value. Each nonzero entry of the sparse matrix is represented
>       by a node. The zero terms are not explicitly stored. The nodes are linked
>       together to form two circular lists. The first list, the row list, is made
>       up by linking nodes by rows and within rows by columns using the right
>       eld. The second,list, the column list, is made up by linking nodes via the
>       down field. In this list, nodes are linked by columns and within columns
>       by rows. These two lists share a common header node. In addition, a
>       node is added to the dimensions of the matrix.

I hope to overload operator >> and also add and transpose methods:

```
 istream & operator>>(istream & in, sparseMatrixLinked<T> x); 
//The input format is as follows. 

4   4   3  //   # of rows, # of cols, # of nonzero entries
0   0   2  // row #, col #, item value #
0   3   1
1   1   7

void sparseMatrixLinked<T>::add(sparseMatrixLinked<T> &b,sparseMatrixLinked<T> &c);
        // c = (*this) + b 


void sparseMatrixLinked<T>::transpose(sparseMatrixLinked<T> &b) ;
// b is transpose of *this.
```

I cannot figure out a solution. Could anyone provide some advice? Thank you very much!

Comment: Draw a picture. Pictures always help me.

Comment: What do you want `operator >>` to do?  You didn't specify.  If you want it to read from istreams, then explain the format you expect the input to take.

Comment: For `add`, what do you want to do, precisely?  Do you want to overlap the matrices and add the `val` entries in any cell existing in both, or to make a larger matrix by arranging the second next to the first somehow, or what?

Comment: I know that, but do you mean the matrices are added in the mathematical sense (i.e. cell-by-cell with guaranteed equal size)?  There are other ways you could define "adding" two matrices, and I have no idea what kind of application domain you're working in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `transpose`, you could traverse one list, swapping all the links and row/col pointers.  In pseudocode:

```
set node to header
do {
    swap node.row and node.col
    swap node.right and node.down
    node = node.right
} while node != header;
```

Here's `addNode`, one (inefficient) solution is to add individual nodes by traversing both lists until you find the insertion point for your node, and then add it there.  It can be used on every node in a second matrix to implement something like `+=`; adding a copy of the current matrix first gives `add`.

```
newnode = allocate node with row, col, val set, pointers null
top = header
while (top.down != header and 
       (top.down.col < newnode.col or
        (top.down.col == newnode.col and
         top.down.row < newnode.row)
       )
    top = header.down
left = header
while (left.right != header and 
       (left.right.row < newnode.row or 
        (left.right.row == newnode.row and 
         left.right.col < newnode.col)
       )
      )
    left = left.right
if top == left
    // if I'm thinking correctly this means newnode is already there
    assert top.row == newnode.row and top.col == newnode.col
    top.val += newnode.val
    delete newnode
else
    newnode.right = left.right
    newnode.down = top.down
    left.right = newnode
    top.down = newnode
```

There are much more efficient ways to implement `add` but those are left as an exercise to the reader.

`operator>>` should look more or less like this:

```
istream & operator>>(istream & in, sparseMatrixLinked<T> x)
{
   x.clear();

   int rows, cols, vals;
   in >> rows >> cols >> vals;
   for (int i = 0; i > vals; i++) {
       int row, col, val;
       in >> row >> col >> val;
       x.addNode(row, col, val);
   }
```

}

You could use an algorithm like the above to implement `addNode`.  Again, that's very slow, though.  Here's a hint: if the input is sorted in any way, you can take advantage of that to make building the matrix much faster.  Even if not, a more efficient way of doing arbitrary node inserts will make things better.

Comment: @Walter Thanks! For the `transpose` code, because I need a new matrix. So, I should first copy the matrix and then swap down and right. Is there any way to copy the matrix? I think for hours but cannot find an efficient way. Thanks.

Comment: Could you say a little about the more efficient way? I have to go to bed now. it is too late. I will think about your methods in the morning.

Comment: Copying the matrix first is definitely the simplest option for transpose.  You could copy and transpose in one pass but I think you might need some auxiliary data structures to do it right.

Comment: For adding individual nodes, keep in mind that as long as an existing node has lesser-or-equal `row` AND `col` values compared to the new node, it will have pointers leading to the desired parents of the new node in both lists.

Comment: For combining two sparse matrices, I'm not actually quite sure what you want.  If you are trying to overlap them, you could probably build a new matrix by following, say, the `down` links on both inputs and merging as you go, while maintaining a map of pointers to last entries seen on each row; as you add nodes, a `lower_bound` search on the map would find the node to the left of it so you could fix up the `right` pointer there.

Comment: The `add` method above adds a node to a matrix, presuming there is currently a zero in that cell.  To allow it to be used for adding matrices together, you would copy the first matrix, then loop over all the nodes in the second, calling the `addNode` on each.  I've updated `addNode` a bit to deal having a non-zero value present already.